# NodeJS: Server.on-listenerfunction doesn't exist when exporting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, listener

I am using server.js to start the server and router.js to listen to the requests. When I try to access the server, nothing happens and I can't reach it, I assume so, because the server.on function doesn't execute. Everything works, when I put it just in the server.js tho, so the error seems to be in with the exports/imports, but I can't figure out what it is.

server.js:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");
const template = require("./template.js");

const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer();

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on localhost:${port}`);
})

module.exports = server;
```

router.js:

```
const server = require("./server.js");
const template = require("./template.js");

server.on("request", (req, res) => {
    let url = req.url;
    let method = req.method;
    let html;
    console.log("received req");
    res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8" });

    if(url.endsWith("/feedback") && method == "GET") {
        html = template.createHtml("Liste der Feedbacks");
    } else {
        html = template.createHtml(`Methode: ${method}, URL: ${url}`);
    }

    res.end(html);
})
```

Comment: I am a little rusty on this but aren't you referring to your `server.js`'s `on` function? There is none of course, so it doesn't exist.

Comment: You are importing the router.js from within the server.js, which in turns imports the server.js which imports the router.js.... an so on. Something's, not right in here.

Comment: Why not trying to remove the server dependency from the router.js altogether, and just export the handler function, e.g module.exports = handleRequest. Then, inside the server.js you can do: server.on( "request", handleRequest)

Comment: @KostasMinaidis no it's a university task I am doing to practice, the task clearly wants the listener functionality seperate from the server.js. My code works and does what it's supposed to, it just seems to fall apart, when I try to export the server to have the listener in router.js

Comment: @BalázsBörcsök the on function would be part of the server object itself which I am exporting from server.js. At least thats the plan, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Hmmm... but the listener functionality is in the server.js right now though.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis I might have worded that a bit confusing, sorry. I meant the event listener/request handler is supposed to be in router.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to import the `router.js` and have the `server` object accessible in that file and execute the `on` method on it, one way to do it is by passing the `server` while requiring the `router.js` file as follows:

server.js:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer();

const router = require("./router.js")( server );

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

router.js:

```js
const template = require("./template.js");

module.exports = function handleRequest( server ){
    return server.on("request", (req, res) => {
        let url = req.url;
        let method = req.method;
        let html;
        console.log("received req");
        res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8" });
    
        if(url.endsWith("/feedback") && method == "GET") {
            html = template.createHtml("Liste der Feedbacks");
        } else {
            html = template.createHtml(`Methode: ${method}, URL: ${url}`);
        }
    
        res.end(html);
    })
}
```

Whatever pattern you try, make sure to avoid [Circular dependencies](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/circular-dependency-nodejs-modules-nihal-kaul/).

Also, as a general recommendation, I would suggest that you try and avoid `tight coupling` in modules such as these whenever possible. Ideally, the `router` module should not be tightly coupled to the `server` module.

Comment: Is there also a way without calling the function in server.js? Like I see that the function is in router, which is good, but it's called in server.js which is kind of a problem in my case

Comment: The only way to do it, as I see it, is to initialize the server from within the router.js file (const server = http.createServer()), setup the server listeners (server.on()) and export the server from the router.js, and call the listen method on it.

Comment: But, to be honest, I'm feeling that either the instructions are unclear or you've misinterpreted them. Make sure to go through the exercise requirements to see that this is exactly what you must implement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah, the requirements are a bit unclear, I now solved it similar to what you proposed. What I take from this now, is that it is not possible to export an object like server to call its functions in another file?

Comment: @FerryHömig You definitely CAN export the server object, import and use it in another file, but you must make sure that the file that exports the server object does NOT in turn import the file that imports the server object, as this is going to result in a Circular/Cyclic Dependency problem. In general, we try to avoid Circular Dependencies.

Comment: @FerryHömig Also, in the code that you have pasted in your question above, there's a big difference between which of the 2 files (router/server) is going to initialize the app, e.g. are you going to run the app via node router.js or node server.js? In the first case, everything will work just fine, but in the latter nothing will happen as the router.js file is never loaded and thus never gets executed. Try to follow the flow of execution, and you'll understand what happens in each case. Experiment with simpler import/export setups in order to get more comfortable with how modules work in Node.